# Argo Workflow Engine entities at k8s dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, argoproj, argo-workflows

Has anybody knows how can I configure argo or k8s to see Workflows at dashboard

Comment: What do you mean under "Workflows at dashboard"?

Comment: I mean, at k8s dashboard we can see entities ike Pod or Deployment, can we see also Workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argo's workflow concept is a [`CRD`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) and the dashboard [currently doesn't support `CRD`s](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2493). There is an [Argo-specific UI](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-ui) that you can use if you're looking for more visibility.